# Protractor - Enter Key not working

Tags: return, sendkeys, protractor

I am trying to run some protractor tests in Safari (they run fine in Chrome).

The problem seems to be that the return key is not working correctly in `sendKeys()` method. 
The value is being not send ( - is undefined)

Here is what I did on the input object:

`input.sendKeys(value + '\n');`

Also, I tried 
`input.sendKeys(value + protractor.Key.ENTER);`

But getting the same results.

Comment: It sounds like you are attempting to submit a form using the enter key. Is there a button the user can click?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [webdriverjs doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#1724), the correct syntax seems to be:

```
input.sendKeys(value, protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Have you also tried to send the text and the enter key separately:

```
input.sendKeys(value);
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: No, I tried that and it does not work in safari (Chrome/Firefox is fine). It still returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

If you want to use a combination of keys in protractor, try this (for example SHIFT + TAB):

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
```